# NoSql strategies for providing authorization to rows of data

Tags: c#, authorization, nosql

Coming from a sql background.  When I want to limit access to data based upon certain attributes of a user, I can create a view and use the view as a filter in limiting what data a user sees based upon the criteria in the view.  This approach relies upon relationships and so far it has worked for me.  Looking at NoSql and the shift in strategy and concept, I am confused about how to implement this consdering the nature of NoSql.  What is the NoSql approach to a problem such as this?  When users are only privy to certain rows based upon their user type?  For example, say an administrator can see all of the records for a particular group and a generic user can only see their records and certain group level items, group photos, group messaging, etc. that are public within a group.  I am really trying to wrap my head around not thinking in terms of the sql approach to this problem but I am new to NoSql so that has been a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL databases are conceptually different from relational databases in many aspects. Authorization and security in general is not their primary focus. But, most of them have evolved in that area, and they have fine-grained authorization. Basically, it depends on a particular database.

For example, Cassandra has column-level permissions in plan (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12859), HBase has cell-level permissions (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_hbase_authorization.html). On the other hand, MongoDB is generally schemaless and it has different (more complex) document-oriented data model, which makes it hard to implement low level access control. Additionally, MongoDB has views.

So, if DBMS you are using doesn't have built-in authorization on expected level, it has to be implemented inside an application that interacts with db (if there are more than one application, things can get tricky, and some usage rules have to be established). Using denormalized models is a common thing, so different roles/groups can interact with different tables/collections which contain data that only that role/group can see (basically, it's a simulation of RDBMS views). This denormalized approach usually takes more space and it requires keeping copies in sync. If DBMS supports projection, subset of columns/fields can be presented for different roles/groups (that way, at least some of processing is done on db side).

I hope this helps, though it's a late answer.